# How to add a background color to items using PlantUML

Tags: background-color, plantuml

In Visual Studio Code i'm trying to add a backgroundcolor to my "items". According to the documentation it should work like this:

```
@startuml LogAdministration_C1
!include  ../../../src/diagrams/plantuml/C4/C4_Context.puml
HIDE_STEREOTYPE()

AddElementTag("bgcolor", $bgColor="#335DA5") 

System(logA, "Log Administraion", $tags="bgcolor")
System(logCF, "label")

Rel(logA, logCF, "IO")

@enduml
```

[image]

Sadly it does not. Does anyone have an idea?

Comment: According to my tests it works, I had to change the included puml file to `!include https://raw.githubusercontent.com/plantuml-stdlib/C4-PlantUML/master/C4_Context.puml` so I had the file available (maybe your file contains a bug or cannot be found?). When changing `#335DA5` in `#FF0000` the background in the "Log.." field is red.

Comment: Hey albert, when i use "your" C4_Context.puml file it also works for me. Very interesting. Anyway, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Just change "AddElementTag" to "AddSystemTag"

```
@startuml LogAdministration_C1
!includeurl ../lib/ImportsAndConfigs.puml
HIDE_STEREOTYPE()

AddSystemTag("bgcolor", $bgColor="#335DA5")

System(logA, "Log Administraion", $tags="bgcolor")
System(logCF, "label")

Rel(logA, logCF, "IO")

@enduml
```